# Nested enumerations in Java

Tags: java, enums, nested

I am trying to implement a nested enumeration in Java. The following interface does the job quite well, but the static valueOf() method isn't available. Is there any way to 'reconstruct' it?

Thanks for all your answers!

```
public static interface ANIMAL
{
    public static final ANIMAL UNKNOWN = _.UNKNOWN;

    public static enum _ implements ANIMAL
    {
        UNKNOWN,
    }

    public static enum MAMMAL implements ANIMAL
    {
        ;
        public static enum LAND implements ANIMAL
        {
            HORSE,
            COW;
        }
        public static enum SEA implements ANIMAL
        {
            WHALE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Implementing inheritance with enums which are not inheritable does not seem such a good idea...

Comment: But it works quite fine, except the above mentioned problem...

Comment: Well that was my point (the problem you mention) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the example you provided is a [sscce](http://sscce.org) or your real implementation, but remember that you don't have to be a Mammal to be a land creature. Further, enums are not inheritable, so you might best be off with something like this:

```
public enum Type {
  MAMMAL, REPTILE, INSECT;
}

public enum Region {
  LAND, SEA, AIR;
}

public enum Animal {
  HORSE (Type.MAMMAL, Region.LAND),
  WHALE (Type.MAMMAL, Region.SEA),
  LIZARD (Type.REPTILE, Region.LAND),
  ANT (Type.INSECT, Region.LAND),
  WASP (Type.INSECT, Region.AIR);

  private Type t;
  private Region r;
  private Animal(Type t, Region r) {
    this.t = t;
    this.r = r;
  }
  public Type getType() { return t; }
  public Region getRegion() { return r; }
}
```

This way you're not trapped in an inheritance hierarchy, you can change different descriptors around however you want.

---

Ok so now I understand what you want. It IS possible, but you'd have to separately implement each enumeration. The problem is that you can't do `ANIMAL.valueOf("HORSE")`, but you could do `ANIMAL.MAMMAL.LAND.valueOf("Horse")`. Another option would be to create a `HashMap<String, Enum>`, and use that to approximate the functionality, but it would be difficult to use because it would be difficult to cast to the right subclass. But it would have all the methods of `Enum`...

Comment: I would like to access e.g. the horse like this:
ANIMAL horse = ANIMAL.MAMMAL.LAND.HORSE;
That is not possible with your solution. Isn't it?

Comment: What about `ANIMAL horse = ANIMAL.LAND.MAMMAL.HORSE` should that work too?

Comment: No, that should not work. However I think that what I'd like is simply impossible in Java...